# Compare MouseMove event stream, mouse location doesn't decrease

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive

I have a Windows Forms application and I'm using Rx to query the MouseMove event-stream and produce a result based on the Locations (current and previous) of mouse. My code looks like:
(The label1 shows the results and label2 shows a "log" with the current and previous location.)

```
        var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove");
        observable                
            .PairWithPrevious()
            .Select(tuple =>
                    {
                        if (tuple.Item2 == null || tuple.Item1 == null) return Tuple.Create(0, 0);
                        var currPosition = tuple.Item2.EventArgs.Location;
                        var prevPosition = tuple.Item1.EventArgs.Location;
                        var x = 0;
                        if (currPosition.X > prevPosition.X) x = 1;
                        else if (currPosition.X < prevPosition.X) x = -1;
                        var y = 0;
                        if (currPosition.Y > prevPosition.Y) y = 1;
                        else if (currPosition.Y < prevPosition.Y) y = -1;
                        label2.Text = string.Format("Curr X: {0} * Y: {1} |||| Prev X: {2} * Prev Y: {3}", currPosition.X, currPosition.Y, prevPosition.X, prevPosition.Y);
                        return Tuple.Create(x, y);
                    })
            .Subscribe(x =>
                       {
                           label1.Text = string.Format("X: {0} ** Y: {1}", x.Item1, x.Item2);
                       });
```

The PairWithPrevious function:

```
    public static IObservable<Tuple<TSource, TSource>> PairWithPrevious<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source)
    {
        return source.Scan(
            Tuple.Create(default(TSource), default(TSource)),
            (acc, current) => Tuple.Create(acc.Item2, current));
    }
```

The issue is: when you move the mouse to the left or upward, the previous and current (x, y) are the same values and the result (label1) never shows "-1" value.

I've tried using Zip function in order to compare previous and current value, but the result is the same:

```
      Zip(observable.Skip(1), Tuple.Create)
```

So, why occurs this? and how to fix it?

Comment: If they were the same values, then you would always get -1.  (`currPosition.X > prevPosition.X` would always return `false`). So I suspect there's something else wrong with your code. Is this the complete sample?

Comment: Note that it doesn't appear to be a problem with your Rx query.

Comment: Your `Zip` example wouldn't work anyway unless you used `Publish` as well, but `Scan` is fine. (`Scan` is my preferred way of pairing.)

Comment: Hi @DaveSexton, yes, is the complete sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you watch how often the MouseMove event fires you will see what is causing the issue. I've updated your code to include a count.  I also added a simple listview with three columns and set the Listview's view to detail so it's quite visible.

Some of my code is different than yours.  It's mainly a style issue.  But I changed PairWithPrevious to be just WithPrevious and hid the Tuple

```
//http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=213 with a tweak to hide the Tuple
public static IObservable<TResult> WithPrevious<TSource, TResult>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> projection)
{
    return source.Scan(Tuple.Create(default(TSource), default(TSource)),
                       (previous, current) => Tuple.Create(previous.Item2, current))
                 .Select(t => projection(t.Item1, t.Item2));
}
```

The RX Select operator has an overload of int that is just a counter.  I'm going to use that to add to an anonymous object to chain down.  The WithPrevious now just Projects out to another anonymous object that contains the data we want.   Then in subscribe we'll update the two labels and the new listview.

```
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove")
                                   .Select((eventPattern, count) => new {eventPattern.EventArgs, Count = count})
                                   .WithPrevious((previous, current) =>
                                       {
                                           var currentPoint = current == null
                                                                  ? new Point(0, 0)
                                                                  : current.EventArgs.Location;
                                           var previousPoint = previous == null
                                                                   ? new Point(0, 0)
                                                                   : previous.EventArgs.Location;

                                           return
                                               new
                                                   {
                                                       CurrentPoint = currentPoint,
                                                       PreviousPoint = previousPoint,
                                                       Count = current == null ? 0 : current.Count
                                                   };
                                       })
                                   .Subscribe(a =>
                                       {
                                           label2.Text =
                                               String.Format(
                                                   "Curr X: {0} * Y: {1} |||| Prev X: {2} * Prev Y: {3} - Count = {4}",
                                                   a.CurrentPoint.X, a.CurrentPoint.Y,
                                                   a.PreviousPoint.X, a.PreviousPoint.Y,
                                                   a.Count);


                                           label1.Text = String.Format("X: {0} ** Y: {1}",
                                                                       a.CurrentPoint.X.CompareTo(
                                                                           a.PreviousPoint.X),
                                                                       a.CurrentPoint.Y.CompareTo(
                                                                           a.PreviousPoint.Y));
                                           var listItem = new ListViewItem(a.Count.ToString());
                                           listItem.SubItems.Add(a.CurrentPoint.X.ToString());
                                           listItem.SubItems.Add(a.CurrentPoint.Y.ToString());
                                           listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
                                           listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
                                       });
```

You can now see if you are slow moving the mouse down or to the right the event fires just once but, on my computer, if you move the mouse up or to the left the smallest number of events I could get is three and the last one is always the same as the previous one.  That's why it's always zero, zero.

Now if we add .DistinctUntilChanged(a => a.CurrentPoint) right after the WithPrevious and before the Subscribe you can get more what you are looking for.  I say most because moving the mouse diagonal the events on my pc wouldn't ever have both the X and Y different.  You might be able to play around with Throttle - something like .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25), CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance)  After the Select and before WithPrevious.  That helped on my PC but wasn't perfect.

Comment: :o you are the author of the comment on this post...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using DistinctUntilChanged works well in my machine, but using Throttle (I've tried it before) have different results... I'm going to apply changes and play with code, if I need any advice... I'll comment :P. Thanks again.